# Reversing lines of a text file through function in class

Tags: python, oop, reverse

I am trying to make a class that receives file name in constructor and has function that reverses all the lines in that file.

```
class exampleOne:
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName

    def reverse(self):
        file = open(self.fileName, "w")
        for value in list:
            file.write(value.rstrip() + "\n")
        file.close()

a = exampleOne("textExample.txt")
a.reverse()

Text file:
1.
2.
3.
The output i want in the existing file:
3.
2.
1.
```

But when I try running this, i get this error:
"TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable".. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing a line before the for statement: "list = file.readlines()"

Comment: That particular error is because you're trying to iterate over `list` in the line `for value in list:`, which is a built-in type. You might want to iterate over `file` (which is another built-in which you're redefining in this case, but let's leave that for now). However, this code wouldn't do what you want anyway. Exactly what result do you want?

Comment: @Cyphase I want to reverse lines in the existing file

Comment: @AsapCancel, what do you mean reverse? Show us a short 2-3 line input file and your desired output.

Comment: And why exactly do you want/need a class for this?

Comment: So basicly I am trying to load the file, reverse all lines in it..so for example:
1.
2.
I want it to be
2.
1.

Comment: You can check my answer, this is working. @AsapCancel

Comment: @AsapCancel, is that '1. 2.' supposed to be one line, or two lines? There's a difference. It'll be much easier if you just show an exact input file and output file by modifying your question. :)

Comment: Your example looks good and i think it will help me a bit, but yeah @Cyphase , its supposed to be two lines, I will modify question in a second :d

Comment: You should accept an answer, even if it's your own :).

Comment: Apperantly I am available to accept my answer in two days, dunno why,tried 2 times

Comment: @AsapCancel I don't mean to be offensive, nor do I say this to get that sweet reputation, but you should accept mine or Cyphase's answer. While your professor gave you homework and your answer is the correct solution to that homework, it's not the correct answer here on StackOverflow (somebody correct me if I'm wrong). You asked a question, and we provided you the correct solution (no class needed!). It's not what your professor wants, but it's the best solution. He's wrong, we're right.

Comment: I understand, its gucci, your answers helped me alot however, anyway. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you might think that you need a class here, you don't. Unless you got more code that you're not telling us about, the correct solution is to not use a class at all.
Your class contains one string and has one method in it, there's nothing wrong with a simple function. It's in fact much better option compared to a class:

```
def reverse_lines(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
    with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(lines[::-1])  # reversed(lines)
```

If your file does not end into a newline (`\n`), you will need to manually add the newline. Here's what the function might look like in its final form:

```
def reverse_lines(file_path):
    """
    Takes a path to a file as a parameter `file_path`
    and reverses the order of lines in that file.
    """

    # Read all the lines from the file
    with open(file_path) as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()

    # Make sure there are more lines than one
    if len(lines) <= 1:
        return

    # If the file doesn't end into a newline character
    if not lines[-1].endswith('\n'):

        # Add it and remove the newline from the first (to be last) line
        lines[-1] += '\n'
        lines[1] = lines[1][:-1]

    # Reverse and output the lines to the file
    with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(lines[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
for value in list:
```

refers to something called `list`, but you don't have anything by that name in your program. Without a local definition, `list` refers to the built-in Python type `list`, which is not something you can use like that in a `for` loop.

It's usually a good idea to avoid redefining the names of built-in Python objects like `list`. In your case, you might use `lines` to represent a list of the lines in a file.

(You'll have to add code to actually *read* the lines from the file, too.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code, I think that this will be work for you. If you want you can write the output to the file.

```
class exampleOne:
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName

    def reverse(self):

        with open('textExample.txt') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()    
        for i in lines:
            words = i.split()
            sentence_rev = " ".join(reversed(words))
            print sentence_rev
        f.close()
a = exampleOne("textExample.txt")
a.reverse()

Example txt file : 
Dummy Words
Dummy Words

Output:
Words Dummy
Words Dummy
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a class for this; a function will do just fine.

```
def reverse_lines_in_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as input_file:
        lines = input_file.readlines()

    lines.reverse()

    # If the new first line, which was the old last line,
    # doesn't end with a newline, add one.
    if not lines[0].endswith('\n'):
        lines[0] += '\n'

    with open(filepath, 'w') as output_file:
        for line in lines:
            output_file.write(line)


reverse_lines_in_file('textExample.txt')
```

There are better ways to do this, but as you seem to be a novice (nothing wrong with that :) ), I think this will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, the code is working now. this is the final version that works perfectly

```
class exampleOne:
    def __init__(self, filePath):
        self.filePath = filePath

    def reverse(self):
        file = open(self.filePath, "r")
        list = file.readlines()
        file.close()

        list.reverse()

        file = open(self.filePath, "w")
        for value in list:
            file.write(value)
        file.close()

a = exampleOne("textExample.txt")
a.reverse()
```

Comment: You don't need a class for this, and you shouldn't use a class if you don't need one. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: I know that i dont need class for this, but i was supposed to practise it by doing it this way, thanks thought for the assisting a lot

Comment: Sure, no problem :). Out of curiosity, why were you supposed to practice it this way? According to whom?

Comment: I understand, I was just wondering where the assignment came from? Which textbook/website/professor/etc? It's teaching you bad practices :P.

Comment: Its professor from university :D but yeah you are right, this is definitely not a good way to do this

Comment: @AsapCancel Show this question and the answers to your professor. Either you understood something wrong and he can correct you, or he's not that good of a teacher and he could learn something himself. You seriously should not use a class here. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)'s a good video about not forcing classes when you don't need them, I recommend it to everyone.

Comment: Nah, the homework was exactly like this: write a class that in constructor receives name of file and has method called reverse.. etc etc, so i definitely did not misunderstood. Will watch the video